# JSON DECODE Array parse sample value issue

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, parsing

I'm trying to input json strings as:
http://prntscr.com/kt8i8a

```
{"0":168,"1":168}

{"168":1,"168":2}

{"168":70000,"168":80000}
```

My purpose is getting 2 values with id=168 to save in DB
when i use `json_decode('{"168":1,"168":2}',true)`
I get the result with only value :

```
array:1 [
  168 => 2
]
```

How many ways to parse full values?, thanks

Comment: Having two occurrences of the same key is not valid JSON.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in PHP, or in JSON.

Comment: It makes sense, doesn't it? Having two of the same key that point to two different values defeats the purpose of a key. You're supposed to be able to reference that key to look up a value.

Comment: that's my project. I have to add 2 products that have the same id but different option values.

Comment: Well, your sentence "I'm trying to input json strings" is incorrect.  If that's the data you're being given, and have you no control over it, then what you are being give in _not_ JSON.  It's just a text string that's trying to look like JSON.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is not a valid json syntax, try to fix it.

If you don't can because you cant influence the api because you don't have developed it, you could try it over regex parsing like this :

```
<?php
//print out the result
var_dump(getInvalidCustomJson('{"0":168,"1":168}'));

function getInvalidCustomJson($json){
    $res = array(); // result array which get returned
    preg_match_all('/"([0-9]+)".([0-9]+)/m',$json, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER); // matching a key between "..." and a value which get send afterwards
    for($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++){ // go through all results
        $std = array();
        $std[$result[1][$i]] = $result[2][$i]; // insert key and value from the groups into the array
        $res[] = $std; // add the array to the result array
        // $res[$result[1][$i]] = $result[2][$i]; wont work because it will
        // overwrite the key like json decoder does
    }
    return $res; // return array
}
?>
```

Comment: If he dont can influence the Output because it comes from an api its not his fault. If he can he should definitly Pick a other solution

Comment: @BlackNetworkBit have all the time to add just a little explanation to the solution given for the op to understand of course. At the end SO is also for people that want to learn and not just ask someone to give a solution.

Comment: @Sigma i added comments to it, if you have something to add go for it

Answer (score 4):

Keys in objects/dictionaries are unique, so the last key's value will be final and replace all other values before that.

Two solutions, either put 2 objects inside an array:

```
[
    {
        "168": "1"
    },
    {
        "168": "2"
    }
]
```

or have an object with key of `168` with 2 values:

```
{
    "168": [
        "1",
        "2"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, i hope you can modify the format of the encoded json adding some extra info to make it a multidimensional array. There are different ways to have same key index with different value and one may be like this:

```
{"data":
  [
    {"168":"1"},{"168":"2"}
  ]
}
```

in this case you can get the desired result and access the values, otherwise is not possible like in your code because you have a duplicate unique key index.
Hope is clear and helps you.

Comment: Thanks, it's also helpful for me